# Drupal node templates which apply to more than one content type. Possible?

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I've started looking at content type specific `node.tpl.php` files. However, say I have two content types, and wish both to be displayed in a similar manner, but not apply this to every content type (at the level of `node.tpl.php`).

It seems a bit of an overkill to have two identical files for `node--contenttype_1.tpl.php` and `node--contenttype_2.tpl.php` which are the same? Is there a way to have a multi-content-type template for this?

In case you're wondering the reason for having two different content types in the first place, one is a simpler version of the other, has different URL generation rules (via pathauto), and fewer fields associated with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implement a [preprocess function](http://drupal.org/node/223430) that adds a [template suggestion](http://drupal.org/node/223440).

Assuming your theme is called `EXAMPLETHEME`, your content types are `content_type_1` and `content_type_2` and the template file is called `node--example.tpl_php`, add the following function to the file `template.php` of your theme:

```
function EXAMPLETHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->type == 'content_type_1' || $node->type == 'content_type_2') {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'node__example';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An "evil" suggestion would be to create a symlink `node--contenttype_2.tpl.php` which points to `node--contenttype_1.tpl.php`. I have actually used stuff like this on production sites.